# How to change a specific icon image from Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottom-nav-view

I need to implement a Bottom Navigation View in my android app. The middle icon needs to be an image, the company logo. But when I run the app it appears only a grey filled rounded icon. The images above show what I want and what I'm getting.

What I want:
[image]

What I get:
[image]

I already tried others questions in this website, but every answer tells to change the iconTintList from XML with a drawable, but the center icon is a vector with more than one color.

When I tried to set null to setIconTintList method, works for the middle icon but the others icons change to original color too.

```java
//This doesn't work to other icons, only for the middle one 
mBottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

I also tried to get the menu and set the icon tint list only for the middle one, like the code above, but doesn't work too.

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    mBottomNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_buy).setIconTintList(null);
}
```

This is the XML implementation:

```xml
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/kmv_background"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_item_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

This is the java implementation:

```java
mBottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think there's a short way. Use this first:

```
   mBottomNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Then do the designs yourself. Don't forget to separate the buttons as clicked and not clicked.

**Example Home Button XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Clicked-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homeclicked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <!--Not Clicked-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homenotclicked" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

And add them to the view:
**Example bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homebuttons"
        android:icon="@drawable/homebuttonxml />

 <!--Other Buttons...-->

</menu>
```

And finally, Link view to bottomnavigationview

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView    
     android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
     app:elevation="0dp"
     app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">  
   
</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, this is what I looking for.

Comment: Excelent! Thank you so much!

Comment: With the new versions, a short version has been provided

Answer (score 0):

For a particlar icon, this can be used:

```
MenuItemCompat.setIconTintMode(binding.bottomNav.menu.getItem(3), null);
```